# Tkinter box issues- Entry, Labelbox, Text all take up space from side to side, grid crashes computer

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.2

I'm using a tkinter canvas and trying to make a chat box on the right side of my game. However, I found that when I do...

```
import turtle
import tkinter as tk
master = tk.Tk()
w = tk.Canvas(master,width=1155,height=600,cursor='cross_reverse', bg='#101010')
shift = 1.000

sc = turtle.TurtleScreen(w)
tu = turtle.RawTurtle(sc)
e = tk.Entry(master, bg = '#000', fg = '#03f', font = 'Courier', justify='right', insertbackground = '#101010',width='115')
lb = tk.Listbox(master,height=3)
#e.grid(row=3,column=3)
sc.bgcolor("#101010")

txt = tk.Text(master,state="disabled")

txt.pack()
lb.pack()
w.pack()
sc.tracer(100)
drawcontinents()    #Draws stuff with turtle, works just fine
e.pack()
tk.mainloop()
```

... a few things go wrong.

1.Text and Entry do not seem to want to coexist. I seem to be only able to have one or the other. My plan was to use entry as a chat entry, and display messages in Text. My backup plan is to append messages to label.

2.Text, entry, and Label box take up the entire window in whatever rows they are in, which blocks out the rest of what I am trying to draw. In other words,it puts the text box in the center, with a big gray stripe from side to side across whatever I've drawn. Is there any way to just display the box, and put it to the right?

3.Whenever I try to use the grid system, my whole computer freezes and I have to restart. Is this because the program is taking up more space than I have available, or is this a known bug or problem with installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use both `pack` and `grid` at the same time *for the same containing widget* (ie: for all widgets inside the same frame, toplevel or root window).

What happens is this: grid lays out all the widgets, potentially changing the size of some widgets based on your options (ie: it may grow a widget to stick to the sides of the cell). pack then notices that some widgets changed size in the containing widget it thinks it is responsible for, so it redoes what it thinks is the proper layout. This may change the size of some widgets based on your options. grid then notices that some widgets it thinks it is responsible for change size so it redoes what it does, potentially changing the size of some widgets. pack notices and re-adjusts, grid notices and re-adjusts, pack notices, ... until the end of time.

The solution is simple: only use grid, or only use pack, for all widgets that have a common parent. In this case, all your widgets share the root window as their parent, so they all need to use grid, or they all need to use pack.

Comment: That's perfect. How do I get rid of the borders between the objects? I tried insertborderwidth and bd, bd does something different, and I can't tell what insertborderwidth does

Comment: There are lots of things that contribute to space between objects. There is padding used by grid and pack, there are borderwidths, and many widgets also have a `highlightthickness` attribute. This attribute is used to draw a box around the widget with focus. You can set that attribute to 0 (zero) if you don't care to see a box drawn around with widget with input focus.